# vim syntastic omnisharp-vim giving false errors

Tags: vim

So I am using the omnisharp-vim plugin along with syntastic to show my errors in my web project. When I load a cs file up it is reporting all these errors. When I open the same project up in VS 2015 I do not see the same errors

```
MyProject.Web\Controllers\DashboardController.cs|11 col 52 error| 'MyProjectAuthorizeAttribute' is not a known identifier
MyProject.Web\Controllers\DashboardController.cs|11 col 54 error| Error: ?
MyProject.Web\Controllers\DashboardController.cs|12 col 51 error| 'BaseController' is not a known identifier
MyProject.Web\Controllers\DashboardController.cs|14 col 27 error| 'ILogger' is not a known identifier
MyProject.Web\Controllers\DashboardController.cs|15 col 44 error| 'ILoggerFactory' is not a known identifier
```

Maybe I am missing some configuration in my .vimrc file?

```
" General -----------------------
set nocompatible             " Makes vim better

scriptencoding utf-8         " Setting everything to UTF-8
set encoding=utf-8
set history=256
set timeoutlen=250
set clipboard+=unnamed
let g:autotagTagsFile = ".git/tags"
set tags=./.git/tags,tags,./.git/coffeetags,coffeetags;$HOME

set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile

set hlsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch

" turn off search highlight
nnoremap <leader><space> :nohlsearch<CR>

let mapleader = ','
let maplocalleader = '  '
let g:netrw_banner = 0


" Formatting --------------------
set nowrap

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

set backspace=indent
set backspace+=eol
set backspace+=start

set autoindent
set cindent
set indentkeys-=0#
set cinkeys-=0#
set cinoptions=:s,ps,ts,cs
set cinwords=if,else,while,do
set cinwords+=for,switch,case

set linespace=4
set listchars=tab:>.,trail:.,extends:\#,nbsp:.
set list

" Plugins ------------------------
filetype off 

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-dispatch'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'Shougo/unite.vim'
Plugin 'xero/sourcerer.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'ap/vim-css-color'
Plugin 'groenewege/vim-less'
Plugin 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'jasoncodes/ctrlp-modified.vim'
Plugin 'kaneshin/ctrlp-git-log'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plugin 'mattn/ctrlp-git'
Plugin 'tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'mtscout6/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plugin 'mtscout6/vim-ctags-autotag'
Plugin 'mtscout6/vim-tagbar-css'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-git'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-markdown'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'


call vundle#end() 
filetype plugin indent on

" Rainbow
map <leader>rt :RainbowParenthesesToggle<CR>
map <leader>r( :RainbowParenthesesLoadRound<CR>
map <leader>r[ :RainbowParenthesesLoadSquare<CR>
map <leader>r{ :RainbowParenthesesLoadBraces<CR>
map <leader>r< :RainbowParenthesesLoadChevrons<CR>

" File Type Settings --------------------

" Markdown editing
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal wrap
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal linebreak
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal nolist
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal columns=80
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal tw=80
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal wm=4

" GVIM Options -----------------------
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=L

" Visual ------------------------
syntax on

set showmatch

if has('gui_running')
    set guifont=InputMono:h14

    colorscheme sourcerer

    if has('mac')
    set noantialias
    endif
endif

set novisualbell
set noerrorbells
set vb t_vb=
set laststatus=2

" Airline Settings
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
" Default
let g:airline#extensions#tmuxline#enabled = 0
" Presentation
"let g:airline#extensions#tmuxline#enabled = 1

" Ctrl-P settings
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'r'
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['tag', 'buffertag', 'line', 'funky']
", 'git-log', 'git_branch', 'git_files', 'modified']
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|DS_Store\|git|bower_components'
map <leader>t :CtrlP<CR>
map <leader>gs :CtrlPGitFiles<CR>
map <leader>gb :CtrlPGitBranch<CR>
map <leader>gl :CtrlPGitLog<CR>
map <leader>gm :CtrlPModified<CR>


" ctrlp-modified
map <Leader>m :CtrlPModified<CR>
map <Leader>M :CtrlPBranch<CR>

" Tagbar settings
map <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

" Emmet settings
imap <C-e> <C-y>,

" Multiple Cursor Settings
let g:multi_cursor_use_default_mapping=0
let g:multi_cursor_start_key='<leader>m'
let g:multi_cursor_next_key='<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key='<C-p>'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key='<C-x>'
let g:multi_cursor_quit_key='<Esc>'

" Git Gutter Settings
highlight clear SignColumn
map ]h <Plug>GitGutterNextHunk
map [h <Plug>GitGutterPrevHunk
map <leader>hv <Plug>GitGutterPreviewHunk
map <Leader>hs <Plug>GitGutterStageHunk
map <Leader>hr <Plug>GitGutterRevertHunk

" NERD Tree Settings
map <TAB> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
map <leader>ff :NERDTreeFind<CR>
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
let NERDTreeIgnore=[]

" Syntastic Settings
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
"let g:syntastic_<filetype>_checkers = ['omnisharp']
let g:syntastic_cs_checkers = ['syntax', 'semantic', 'issues']

" Omnisharp settings
let g:OmniSharp_server_type = 'roslyn'
let g:OmniSharp_selector_ui = 'unite'
let g:OmniSharp_selector_ui = 'ctrlp'
let g:OmniSharp_timeout = 1
set noshowmatch
set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview
set splitbelow

augroup omnisharp_commands
    autocmd!

    "Set autocomplete function to OmniSharp (if not using YouCompleteMe completion plugin)
    autocmd FileType cs setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete

    " Synchronous build (blocks Vim)
    "autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <F5> :wa!<cr>:OmniSharpBuild<cr>
    " Builds can also run asynchronously with vim-dispatch installed
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>b :wa!<cr>:OmniSharpBuildAsync<cr>
    " automatic syntax check on events (TextChanged requires Vim 7.4)
    autocmd BufEnter,TextChanged,InsertLeave *.cs SyntasticCheck

    " Automatically add new cs files to the nearest project on save
    autocmd BufWritePost *.cs call OmniSharp#AddToProject()

    "show type information automatically when the cursor stops moving
    autocmd CursorHold *.cs call OmniSharp#TypeLookupWithoutDocumentation()

    "The following commands are contextual, based on the current cursor position.

    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap gd :OmniSharpGotoDefinition<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fi :OmniSharpFindImplementations<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>ft :OmniSharpFindType<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fs :OmniSharpFindSymbol<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fu :OmniSharpFindUsages<cr>
    "finds members in the current buffer
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fm :OmniSharpFindMembers<cr>
    " cursor can be anywhere on the line containing an issue
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>x  :OmniSharpFixIssue<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>fx :OmniSharpFixUsings<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>tt :OmniSharpTypeLookup<cr>
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <leader>dc :OmniSharpDocumentation<cr>
    "navigate up by method/property/field
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-K> :OmniSharpNavigateUp<cr>
    "navigate down by method/property/field
    autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-J> :OmniSharpNavigateDown<cr>

augroup END

nnoremap <leader><space> :OmniSharpGetCodeActions<cr>

vnoremap <leader><space> :call OmniSharp#GetCodeActions('visual')<cr>

" rename with dialog
nnoremap <leader>nm :OmniSharpRename<cr>
nnoremap <F2> :OmniSharpRename<cr>
" rename without dialog - with cursor on the symbol to rename... ':Rename newname'
command! -nargs=1 Rename :call OmniSharp#RenameTo("<args>")

" Force OmniSharp to reload the solution. Useful when switching branches etc.
nnoremap <leader>rl :OmniSharpReloadSolution<cr>
nnoremap <leader>cf :OmniSharpCodeFormat<cr>
" Load the current .cs file to the nearest project
nnoremap <leader>tp :OmniSharpAddToProject<cr>

" (Experimental - uses vim-dispatch or vimproc plugin) - Start the omnisharp server for the current solution
nnoremap <leader>ss :OmniSharpStartServer<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sp :OmniSharpStopServer<cr>

" Add syntax highlighting for types and interfaces
nnoremap <leader>th :OmniSharpHighlightTypes<cr>
"Don't ask to save when changing buffers (i.e. when jumping to a type definition)
set hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

probably VS dont use the same checkers as syntastic ,
run the comand `:SyntasticInfo`
and it will return what checker it is using them you can find why is those errors comming up and how to make you program pass the syntax checker

obs i dont know visual studio but most of your error are `is not a known identifier`

maybe is because it is defined in other file and VS checks it but not syntastic checker